# Computer-friendly name for entity

Tags: terminology, naming

What's the technical term for a computer-friendly name of an entity: e.g. "Guns N' Roses" becomes `guns_n_roses`. This has nothing to to with escaping or sanitizing input, but with aesthetics - looking good in an url.

To clarify, in an "questions" table, you might have the following fields

```
Title: Computer-friendly name for entity
Body: What's the technical term for a compu....
???: computer-friendly-name-for-entity
```

There is a technical term, but I can't remember which. It's a noun, fairly short and (ahem) memorable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress calls it a '[slug](http://www.dailyblogtips.com/wordpress-post-slug/)'

Answer (score 1):

**(to) Sanitize**.

As in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **canonical** representation?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization

The **normalized** name?
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/normalize

Comment: No, there is a (I think) one word term, fairly informal sounding.

Answer (score 0):

Escaped? Machine-readable? Cooked?

Answer (score 0):

Could use '**Alias**'?